# warning in python using selenium - "Anomalous backslash in string: '\P'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've just started using selenium in python. So, i wanted to open a page like instagram in Chrome using selenium. But as soon as the page opens, it closes again immediately. In the second line of my program (see code) I get a warning all the time that says: "Anomalous backslash in string: '\ P'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.pylint (anomalous-backslash-in-string) " Can someone show me what i have to do? Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=de")
```

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" might just need to do // instead of \. Due to what kind of os you use.

Comment: No it's still not working :(

Comment: Try using \\ then.

Comment: It's still crashing

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error, and it turns out if you put an `r` before the address, the error would disappear.

Try this:

```
PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's maybe your chrome driver not in the same version of your chrome

Comment: No, they have the same version. I've already check that

Comment: You should've posted it as a comment